# Email validation in JQuery without using regular expressions?

Tags: jquery, validation, email-validation

I'm very new to jQuery and searching a way to add custom email validation without using Regular Expression.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you

```js
$("#testEmail").click(function () {
    if(emailValidate($("#email").val())) {
        $("#result").text("Is valid email");
    } else {
        $("#result").text("Is NOT valid email");
    }
});

function emailValidate(email){
    var check = "" + email;
    if((check.search('@')>=0)&&(check.search(/\./)>=0))
        if(check.search('@')<check.split('@')[1].search(/\./)+check.search('@')) return true;
        else return false;
    else return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="email" type="text"/><button id="testEmail">Test Email</button>
<span id="result" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Praveen. But it is returning valid on "kkjhfggf@g." this input too.